# Terraform can bypass MFA constraint on AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform, multi-factor-authentication

I use Terraform to manage AWS Resources.

Terraform calls an administrative IAM User who has been MFA locked. But the `terraform apply` and `terraform destroy` commands from my local computer succeed without inputting a unique authentication code.

So, does Terraform bypass the multi-factor authentication?

Answer (score 6):

Terraform is usually setup using API credentials. By default, MFA does not apply to API calls. You should setup and assume a role provisioned exclusively for this if you would like to enable multi-factor authentication on API calls for specific requests (`TerminateInstances` for example).

For more information, see:

[AWS Blog: How to Enable MFA Protection on Your AWS API Calls](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-enable-mfa-protection-on-your-aws-api-calls/)

[Terraform Documentation: AWS](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/)